# What happened to Vika-52?

Tags: oblivion

In the film Jack-52 shows up at the cabin Jack-49 built and where Julia Harper now lives with her and Jack-49's daughter. In Jack-52's entourage (which look like they are all Scavs) there's no Vika clone at all.

None of the Scavs even mention the Vika clones ... if they never brought down or somehow climbed up a tower, they might not even know the Vika clones exist. Both Vika-49 and Vika-52 show a disinclination or disinterest to go the surface.

Was Vika-52 simply left to die from starvation in Tower 52?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if they just left her to starve. As I read somewhere, Vika is the true tragic protagonist of this movie: living a false life, in love with a mirage, and completely forgotten by everybody else. Tough luck, Vika!

Comment: Obligatory [HISHE video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rf5QwVAAxg).

Answer (score 3):

Not only do we not know, but it would appear that the Director left the ending intentionally ambiguous in order to provoke 'fan discussion' after leaving the film. That would seem to include the fate of Vika-52 and the other Jack/Vika pairs:

> **Q:** *At the end of the movie Oblivion, there were two Tom Cruises and only one of them noticed the other. I had trouble wrapping my head
>   around that. It certainly was a good ending because it kept me
>   thinking about the movie for a long time. But I am burning to know
>   what it means. I am thinking not one not two but maybe multiple Tom
>   Cruises? Time travel, multiple universes or something else? -*
>
> **Kosinski:** *I think the idea of the film is — what is it that makes us who we are? Is it the flesh on our bones or is it our souls, our
>   memories? I think the end of the film comes down on the side of saying
>   that it’s our memories, our experiences, our souls that define who we
>   are. **So even though it’s Jack 52 at the end of the film, which is
>   not the same Jack we’ve been following the whole film, he does have
>   the same memories as Julia and therefore, in her mind it really is her
>   Jack. I always knew it was going to be a controversial ending and a
>   provocative idea, but that’s exactly the reason I made this, because I
>   love movies that pose questions like that, and get you thinking and
>   talking about it after the movie’s over.***